# Delete statement - Sub Query should throw error

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, delete-row

I have created two tables, T1 and T2 with one column each, abc and xyz respectively. I have inserted 2 rows (numeric values 1 and 2) in each table.

When I run the command `"select abc from t2"`, it throws an error saying that column abc does not exist in the table T2. However, when I run the command `"delete from t1 where abc in (SELECT abc from t2);"`, 2 rows are deleted.

Shouldn't the delete fail as I have used the same statement which failed in the sub-query?

> create table t1 (abc number); **--Table created**
>
> create table t2 (xyz number); **--Table created**
>
> insert into t1 values (1); **--One row inserted**
>
> insert into t1 values (2); **--One row inserted**
>
> insert into t2 values (1); **--One row inserted**
>
> insert into t2 values (2); **--One row inserted**
>
> SELECT abc from t2; **--ORA-00904 -> Because column abc does not exist in t2**
>
> delete from t1 where abc in (SELECT abc from t2); **--2 rows deleted**

Comment: I guess it is because `abc` in the `DELETE` statement means `abc` in `t1`

Comment: try running a select in your last query to confirm which are the rows that get returned, then you ll have a better idea which abc values were being returned

Comment: Thanks for your replies. When I use the alias "delete from t1 where abc in (SELECT t2.abc from t2), it throws an error. But shouldn't it throw an error even without that as I have used "select abc from t2"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use the table names as alias to make sure table t2 column is getting selected, you will get the error i.e.

```
 delete from t1 where abc in (SELECT t2.abc from t2); --ORA-00904
```

Your original query is not failing because it's using `abc` column of table `t1` **since table `t1` is visible in the subquery.**

Answer (score 1):

Your Delete statement is working because of the abc column name which u have used in Where condition. sub query is executing based on the where condition column, becz we d't use the table alias name.

if u see these queries

select * from t1 where abc in (SELECT abc from t2); -- it 'll give 2 rows

select * from t1 where abc in (SELECT 1 from t2); -- it 'll give 1 row

select * from t1 where abc in (SELECT 2 from t2); -- it 'll retrieve 2nd row

select * from t1 where abc in (SELECT 3 from t2); -- w't get d data

select * from t1 where abc in (SELECT hg from t2); -- Invalid Identifier